# how to get pdfJS to render a pdf from URL?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf.js

i am using PDFJS to render PDFs files using their URL after scanning the current page a js snipet return the  urls. then it passes them to pdfJS. until now everything works the problem show when the PDF is already open in the browser . i take the URL (***.pdf) and pass it the same way as before the difference is that the file is not downloaded and i have this response.

> Warning: Unhandled rejection: Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF "http://geekographie.maieul.net/IMG/pdf/progit.fr.pdf".

(just for the record i dont have CORS issues).

Comment: How do you pass URL? You actually have CORS issue, I don't see "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" for file above (but I can see it for http://async5.org/moz/pdfjs.pdf)

Comment: in fact the probleme was solved using Iframe where i open my pdf(no i dont have cors issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this "http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/"

**Installation**

1. download and unzip file.
2. put "**PDF**" file in this folder.
3. config in "**viwer.js**", edit var DEFAULT_URL.
4. upload folder to server.
5. Have fun!